# Bootstraping Web Page

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

It could sound a little weird but i need some help, the web page have to have a row which have to contain three sections, the first section must have an offset of 1 column, and the space between the sections must be 10px up to this part everything goes well using bootstrap.

Now a second row will have 2 equal sections, its edges have to be align with the edges of the previous row, the first section will have an offset of 1 column and the space between sections must be 10px.

My problem is the second row, how can I create these two sections of the same width with a 10px distance between them and also that its edges aligned to the edges of the previous row.

I let you a picture of the problem.

[image]

The code of my first row is:

```
<div class="barra row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1 colum4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 leftMargin colum4" id="a"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 leftMargin colum4" id="b"></div> 
</div>
```

What will be the second row code??

Answer (score 1):

Well try this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-11">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4 colum4" style="margin-right:10px; width:calc(33.333% - 6.666px);"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 colum4" style="margin-right:10px; width:calc(33.333% - 6.666px);"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 colum4" style="width:calc(33.333% - 6.666px);"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6" style="margin-right:10px; width:calc(50% - 5px);"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6" style=" width:calc(50% - 5px);"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But what about the margins?, with your code the edges are aligned but there are no margins

Comment: okay... well if I see my code there, you have to change the percent if you want to change the amount of cols and so on... But I think this is the only solutions if you want to use margin. If you use padding, you can change the default padding (just left & right) of the col to 5px and change the row padding (left & right) to -5px and just place a custom div (width background-color or border) inside every col. In that way the cols have always the same distance  and the CSS doesn't need to calc anything

Comment: Wow, yep this is exactly i need, but could you please explain me a little bit how you accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

The next row would look like this if I'm interpreting your description correctly.

```
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-5" style="margin-right:10px;></div>
     <div class="col-sm-5></div>
   </div>
```

Comment: With this code the sections are not aligned in the first row we have 3 sections which one of 3 columns, then 3*3 = 9 columns, now the first has an offset of one 9+1 = 10, and the margins are two of 10 px, in brief for the first row we have 10 columns and 20px.

Now the second row must be of the same size in order of edges can be aligned, but i don't know how to split these 10 columns 20px in two sections and 10 px